# Why doesn't my query return correct results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have used these Temp table to return total no of SOlved Cases and Total Number of Pending Cases from same table grouped by DIstrict e.g.

```
District TotalSolvedCases TotalPendingCases
A                3             1
B                8             6
C                7             1
```

I have done this but this doesn't return correct Result

```
SELECT *
INTO #Table1
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID) TotalCases,
           Districts.DistrictName
    FROM Cases
    INNER JOIN ConcernedOffices ON ConcernedOffices.pk_ConcernedOffices_ID = Cases.fk_ConcernedOffices_Cases_ConcernedOfficeID
    INNER JOIN Districts ON Districts.pk_Districts_DistrictID = ConcernedOffices.fk_Districts_ConcernedOffices_DistrictID
    INNER JOIN CaseHearings ON CaseHearings.fk_Cases_CaseHearings_CaseID = Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID
    WHERE CaseHearings.IsClosingDate = 1
    GROUP BY Districts.DistrictName
) d

SELECT *
INTO #Table2
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID) TotalPedningCases,
           Districts.DistrictName
    FROM Cases
    INNER JOIN ConcernedOffices ON ConcernedOffices.pk_ConcernedOffices_ID = Cases.fk_ConcernedOffices_Cases_ConcernedOfficeID
    INNER JOIN Districts ON Districts.pk_Districts_DistrictID = ConcernedOffices.fk_Districts_ConcernedOffices_DistrictID
    INNER JOIN CaseHearings ON CaseHearings.fk_Cases_CaseHearings_CaseID = Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID
    WHERE CaseHearings.IsClosingDate = 0
    GROUP BY Districts.DistrictName
) d

SELECT #Table1.TotalCases AS TotalSolvedCases,
       #Table2.TotalPedningCases,
       #Table1.DistrictName
FROM #Table1
INNER JOIN #Table2 ON #Table2.DistrictName = #Table1.DistrictName
GROUP BY #Table1.TotalCases,
         #Table2.TotalPedningCases,
         #Table1.DistrictName
```

Comment: Can you post actual tables data (with DDL), current result and expected result ?

Comment: Answer not correct.   You really think we can help you based that?

Comment: @Frisbee don't bother, it's done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need one `SELECT`, use `case` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
SELECT COUNT(case when CaseHearings.IsClosingDate = 1 then 1 end) TotalCases,
       COUNT(case when CaseHearings.IsClosingDate = 0 then 1 end) TotalPedningCases,
       Districts.DistrictName
FROM Cases
INNER JOIN ConcernedOffices ON ConcernedOffices.pk_ConcernedOffices_ID = Cases.fk_ConcernedOffices_Cases_ConcernedOfficeID
INNER JOIN Districts ON Districts.pk_Districts_DistrictID = ConcernedOffices.fk_Districts_ConcernedOffices_DistrictID
INNER JOIN CaseHearings ON CaseHearings.fk_Cases_CaseHearings_CaseID = Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID
GROUP BY Districts.DistrictName
```

Comment: thanks sir, yes I have done this but for my practice and learing i want to achieve it via Temp Tables and i can't